# Нужно ли делать обновление каталога на сайте в Frontend верстке?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Добрый день! Относится ли обновление каталога файлов к Front-end верстке?

К примеру, http://flowwow.com/ или https://www.florist.ru/

При выборе фильтра или категории на главной товары обновляются без перезагрузки страницы. Это уже функционал Backend или Frontend?

Comment: Требуется ли реализовывать это при Frontend верстке? Обновление товаров.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что отображением должен заниматься фронтенд, а данные для фронтенда готовить должен бэкэнд. Подготовьте пару json или html файлов с данными, они и будут выполнять роль бэкенда.